# How do I put one <div> element below another <div>

Tags: html, css, css-float, floating

I just finished doing HTML/CSS with Codecademy. One of the "projects" there is to make your own resume. I took the HTML/CSS from that project, and I'm tweaking it to make the resume look better. I'm currently trying to put one `div` - the part of the resume where text about my career objective will go - under another `div`, the `header`. It is, however, not working. The `div` for the "objective" is currently behind the `div` for the header. How on earth do I get that second `div` for the objective to go underneath the first `div`?

I read something about how I should `float` the `header div` to the left and then put `clear:both;` in the `div` for the objective, but that's not working.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
        <p id="name">My Name</p>
        <a href="mailto:myemail@email.com"><p id="email">myemail@email.com</p></a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="objective"></div>
    
    
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    
    <div id="footer">
        <p>1234 Anywhere Street, Brooklyn NY 11216 | Tel: (123) 456-7890</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
border-radius: 5px;
}

#header {
z-index:1;
position: fixed;
width: 98%;
margin-top: -20px;
height: 60px;
background-color: #668284;
margin-bottom: 10px;
float:left;
}

#name {
float:left;
margin-left: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
}

#email{
float:right;
margin-right: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
}


.right p {
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: -10px;
font-family: Garamond, serif;
color: #000000;
}


a:hover {
font-weight: bold;
}

#objective {

height: 50px;
background-color: #668284;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
clear:both;
color: #ffffff;
}


.left {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 49%;
height: 400px;
background-color: #B9D7D9;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.right {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 49%;
height: 400px;
background-color: #F4EBC3;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#footer {
position: relative;
height: 50px;
background-color: #668284;
clear: both;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
}

#footer p {
position: relative;
padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
 <div class="div1">KSD;JSFAJ;SSD;</div>
 <div class="div2">KSD;JSFAJ;SSdfaD;</div>
```

Css with float:

```
 .div1 {
     float: none; 
  }
  .div2 {
     float: none; 
  }
```

Css with display:

```
 .div1 {
     display: inline;
  }
  .div2 {
     display: inline; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated HTML :

```
<div id="header">
    <p id="name">My Name</p>
    <a href="mailto:myemail@email.com"><p id="email">myemail@email.com</p></a>
</div>
<div style="height:50px;width:98%;">
</div>
<div id="objective">Objective goes here</div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>1234 Anywhere Street, Brooklyn NY 11216 | Tel: (123) 456-7890</p>
</div>
```

This will show the `objective div` underneath `header div`.

Also this is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/eyvmhdvz/1/) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is update CSS, This show the responsive your html

```
*{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
                div {
            border-radius: 5px;
            }

            #header {
            width: 98%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #668284;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            #name {
            float:left;
            margin-left: 5px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            color: #ffffff;
            }

            #email{
            float:right;
            margin-right: 5px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            color: #ffffff;
            }


            .right p {
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-top: -10px;
            font-family: Garamond, serif;
            color: #000000;
            }


            a:hover {
            font-weight: bold;
            }

            #objective {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #668284;
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            clear:both;
            color: #ffffff;
            }


            .left {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin-top: 50px;
            width: 49%;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: #B9D7D9;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            .right {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            margin-top: 50px;
            width: 49%;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: #F4EBC3;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            #footer {
            position: relative;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #668284;
            clear: both;
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
            }

            #footer p {
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 15px;
            }
```

Don't ever forget to add this code

```
  *{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
```

So that you won't have empty space on your div

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2waj1v73/)

Answer (score -1):

I think its easier using bootstrap, here is the link http://getbootstrap.com/css/

What bootstrap does is that it creates containers that wrap the content of your site. It divides the site in rows. To do that you need  and . With this bootstrap you can divide your rows in 12 cells.

Here is an example of how I divided my portfolio in 3 columns of 4 spaces

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3 class="text-body"><u>Block vs Inline</u>
          </h3>
            <p class="p-text"><span>Block Elements</span> are those who take the complete line and full width of the page creating a "box".<br>
              <span>Inline Elements</span> are those who doesn´t affect the layout, just the element inside the tag.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3 class="text-body"><u>Selectors</u></h3>
            <p class="p-text"><span>Class selectors</span> are used to target elements with specific attributes<br>On the other hand, <span>id selectors</span> are just for unique elements.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3 class="text-body"><u>Responsive Layout</u></h3>
          <p class="p-text"><span>Responsive Layout</span> is the combination of html and css design to make the website look good in terms of enlargement, shrink and width in any screen (<em>computers, laptops, netbooks, tablets, phones</em>). </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```